# How to select multiple data from table using primary key?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

Hi I am currently doing a micro site which I have finally got working with the data coming from the database and being shown where I need it. My micro site is all about different monarch's in the history of Britain. I am using a bootstrap tabs to show each house during the history of Britain. This is shown in the image below.

[Screenshot of Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfgaC.png)

However the first part I am having no problem with but in the "Danish" tab I only have 3 monarch's associated with this house but when I try to create a new function to match this need it affects all the tabs.

Model

```
public function fetchAll() {
    $sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM monarchy WHERE MonarchyID BETWEEN 1 AND 18';
    $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery);
    $statement->execute();

    $dataSet = [];
    while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        $dataSet[] = new MonarchData($row);
    }
    return $dataSet;
}
```

Denmark Function within Model

```
public function fetchDenmark() {
    $sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM monarchy WHERE MonarchyID BETWEEN 19 AND 21';
    $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery);
    $statement->execute();

    $dataSet = [];
    while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        $dataSet[] = new MonarchData($row);
    }
    return $dataSet;
}
```

Controller

```
<?php
require_once('Model/MonarchData.php');
require_once('Model/MonarchDataSet.php');

session_start();
$view = new stdClass();
$view->pageTitle = 'Brit Monarch';

$monarchDataSet = new MonarchDataSet();
$view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll();


require_once('View/monarchy.phtml');
```

HTML

```
<div id="monarchContainer">
    <?php
    foreach ($view->MonarchDataSet as $MonarchDataSet) {
        ?>
        <div id="monarch">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" 
                        style="font-family:  fantasy; font-style:  initial; font-weight: lighter; text-align: center;">
                        <?php echo '<p>' . $MonarchDataSet->getMonarch() . '</p>'; ?>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <?php
                    ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

How would I use the foreach statement to make the data I want appear in each tab and not affect all the other ?

Any suggestions would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some column with name `MonarchyType`:

```
ALTER TABLE monarchy add COLUMN MonarchyType TEXT;
```

So your model may have one method to find all monarchies or only part by MonarchyType:

```
public function fetchAll($type = false) {
    if(!$type) {
        $sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM monarchy';
        $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery);
    } else {
        $sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM monarchy WHERE MonarchyType = :MonarchyType';
        $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $statement->bindValue(':MonarchyType', $type);
    }

    $statement->execute();

    $dataSet = [];
    while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        $dataSet[] = new MonarchData($row);
    }
    return $dataSet;
}
```

In your app controller you can find only needed monachies:

```
$view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Danish');
```

Or you can find all monarchies in app controller and in your app view you can check `MonarchyType` of all models and show only appropriate models

Comment: Its is coming up with this error - 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind() in C:\Users\lenny\Desktop\BritHist\Model\MonarchDataSet.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\lenny\Desktop\BritHist\monarch.php(11): MonarchDataSet->fetchAll('Danish') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Users\lenny\Desktop\BritHist\Model\MonarchDataSet.php on line 22

Comment: I fix `bind` to `bindValue`. Try new version of code

Comment: Ah thanks how do I differentiate between the different house eg 'Danish', 'Wessex' etc in my controller as all that happens now is all the names of the monarchs appear in the MonarchyType of what I put ?

Comment: Every `MonarchData` now have property `MonarchyType`. you can use this property to check into your controller if this object is suited for you

Comment: How would I achieve this with MonarchyType, I have tried to do this in the controller -

Comment: if ($type == 'Denmark') {
    $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Denmark');
} elseif ($type == 'Normandy') {
   $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Normandy');
} elseif ($type == 'Blois') {
   $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Blois');
} elseif ($type == 'Normandy') {

Comment: elseif ($type == 'Blois') {
   $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Blois');
} elseif ($type == 'Normandy') {
   $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Normandy');
} elseif ($type == 'Plantagent') {
   $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Plantagent');
} elseif ($type == 'Lancaster') {
   $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Lancaster');
}

Comment: elseif ($type == 'York') {
   $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('York');
} elseif ($type == 'Tudor') {
   $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Tudor');
} elseif ($type == 'Stuart') {
   $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Stuart');
}

Comment: elseif ($type == 'Commonwealth') {
   $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Commonwealth');
} elseif ($type == 'Orange') {
   $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Orange');
} elseif ($type == 'Hannover') {
   $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Hannover');
} elseif ($type == 'Gotha') {
   $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Gotha');
} elseif ($type == 'Wessex') {
   $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Wessex');
}

Comment: else {
    $view->MonarchDataSet = $monarchDataSet->fetchAll('Windsor');
}

Comment: However it just errors ? What am I doing incorrectly ?

Comment: We can start to chat because it's too hard to talks into this comments:)

Comment: Hi I would however I can't due as my stackoverflow reputation isn't 2 or higher

Comment: its saying when i join that i have to have reputation 20 to talk ?

Comment: I forgot about this limitation. I'm going home now. Can you publish code somewhere? E.g. github. When I'll be at home I take a look at whole project and help you

Comment: Hi that would be excellent thank you I have put it on GitHub under the repository of BritHist